# End a while loop based on specific amount of user input?

Tags: c++

I was wondering if there is a way to increment and terminate a while loop based on the number of user inputs?  Like, have the user enter a number, do something to said number, then prompt for a new number, rinse and repeat (x) number of times?

Here is my code, or lack thereof lol.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int num_1, num_2, num_3, num_4, num_5;

    //while(user inputs <= 5)
    // cout << "Enter a number" << endl;
    // print that number
    // sum number to total
    // print sum
    // return to beginning of loop


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You don't need 5 variables to hold the inputs, you can sum up the input just inside the loop.

Comment: So some sort of nested while loop would work?

Comment: When you have a defined number of times you want to run a loop, a `for` loop tends to work better for that than a `while` loop. Not that a `while` loop can't be used too, because it can.  It is really a matter of personal style while type of loop you want to use.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do that. You just need a counter which will hold the information regarding the number of loop executions:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int input = 0;
    int sum = 0;

    int user_input = 0; // counter for loop executions

    while (user_input < 5) { // while the loop executed fewer than 5 times, execute the code...
        ++user_input; // ... and mark that the loop executed one more time
        // code logic:
        std::cout << "enter a number: ";
        std::cin >> input;
        sum += input;

        std::cout << "the input: " << input << '\n';
        std::cout << "sum so far: " << sum << '\n';
    }
}
```

Comment: Ahh, so c++ is just smart enough to know that your user_input variable gets incremented by the cin?

Comment: @Cemetery_Gates No the increment happens here: `++user_input;`

Comment: Ok, I see then.  Thank you.